# velocity.js: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, velocity

I am getting started with velocity.js and I included the file like this:

```
 <script src="velocity.js"/> </script>
```

and in the script part I wrote

```
window.onload = function(){
         $("div").velocity({opacity:1});
     }
```

The rest of the function is only the css for the div, so not very important.

The problem I have is that I always get the error code:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

If I use jQuery with .animate no such problem appears (but in the code above I only use velocity).

Comment: Is jQuery being loaded? If you use `jQuery("div")` instead does it still cause an error?

Comment: So you are saying if literally switch out `velocity` for `animate` in the code above it works? Seems incredibly strange to me. Are you loading jquery before velocity?

Comment: I try to use velocity on its own (as in: without jQuery) and if I load jQuery instead of velocity and replace .velocity with .animate the entire thing works fine. 

It also works when I first load jQuery and then load velocity, but I would like to use velocity on its own, which seems to cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an conflict with jQuery. Try .noConflict() to avoid it.
See: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

```
$j.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $j ) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $j can follow here.
});
```

Have you tried this?

```
Velocity(document.getElementById("dummy"), { opacity: 0.5 }, { duration: 1000 });
```

Comment: I wrote it in the comments above already: I try to use velocity without jQuery, so there can't be a conflict(?)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jQuery, you cannot use `$`.

I've never used it before, but if this [tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/09/animating-without-jquery/) is right, you could do:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    divs.forEach(function(el) {
        Velocity(el, {opacity:1});
    });
}
```